# How do I use a struct object to add inside this function archive?

Tags: c, struct

I learned how to use the struct typedef and create a function that creates the vars type PRODUCT for the inventory. However, I saw this example

*extra explanation -> how do I make use of the Hammer product like that? Can I create products for the inventory this way? It is faster than the function?

```
PRODUCT hammer = {"Hammer", 1234, 5.50, 8.99, 4};
```

and do not understand how to include it for the same purpose (to be printed with the report with the other products)

Please could you give some examples of how to use them in this way?

Thanks for your time!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>//standart library
#include <string.h> //to be able to use the strcpy

//Create a struct that represents one product. 
typedef struct {
    //each inventory element will have all those characteristics 
    char name[40];
    short int number;
    double wholesale;
    double retail;
    short int onHand;
} PRODUCT;

//prototypes
void fillInProducts(PRODUCT[], int* pSize); //will use the address of the effectiveSize
void inventoryReport(PRODUCT[], int*);

int main() {
    PRODUCT hammer = {"Hammer", 1234, 5.50, 8.99, 4}; //THIS HERE I WANT TO KNOW HOW TO USE TKS!!

    //Make an array of these objects that represents the items in the store.
    PRODUCT inventory[500]; //for 500 products in the store >> that is a lot of allocated memory;
    int effectiveSize = 0; //to keep track of how many items are in the array inventory, 0 because no products yet

    //Write a function that fills in some test data into the array.
    
    fillInProducts(inventory, &effectiveSize);
    inventoryReport(inventory, &effectiveSize);

    return 0;
}

void fillInProducts(PRODUCT inventory[], int* pSize) {

//** needs to make more products here
    strcpy(inventory[*pSize].name, "Handsaw"); //every time that need to move an array of char or string 
                                               //with a pointer needs to use string copy to do that 
                                               // .name > is the destination, and source
    inventory[*pSize].number = 3456;
    inventory[*pSize].onHand = 12;
    inventory[*pSize].wholesale = 12.34;
    inventory[*pSize].retail = 23.99;
    (*pSize)++; //increase the number of the effective size address
    //needs the () to increment right what is being pointed to, not the pointer *

    strcpy(inventory[*pSize].name, "Test 2"); //every time that need to move an array of char or string 
                                               //with a pointer needs to use string copy to do that 
                                               // .name > is the destination, and source
    inventory[*pSize].number = 3456;
    inventory[*pSize].onHand = 12;
    inventory[*pSize].wholesale = 12.34;
    inventory[*pSize].retail = 23.99;
    (*pSize)++; //increase the number of the effective size address
    //needs the () to increment right what is being pointed to, not the pointer *
}

void inventoryReport(PRODUCT inventory[], int *pSize){
    int i = 0;
    //inventory report
    printf("  Inventory Report  \n");
    printf("  ================  \n\n");
    printf("   Name        Product Number  On Hand   WholeSale  Retail\n");
    printf("   ==========  ==============  =======   =========  ======\n");

    //loop throw the inventory items
    for (i = 0; i < *pSize; i++) {
        printf("%10s %10i %10i %10.2lf %10.2lf\n", 
               inventory[i].name, inventory[i].number, 
               inventory[i].onHand, inventory[i].wholesale, 
               inventory[i].retail);
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to pass the size using pointers to the `inventoryReport` function.

Comment: And I'm not exactly sure what problem you have or what you're trying to do, but structures can be copied using plain assignment. So you could do e.g. `inventory[effectiveSize++] = hammer;` before the call to `inventoryReport`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. `hammer` is a `PRODUCT` type initialized with the values in the brackets `{ ... }`, and then it's never used for anything. Are you saying you want to initialize the `inventory` array with your `hammer` object?

Comment: Yes, how do I make use of the Hammer product? This is what they give me in class to learn and did not explain what I should do with this initialized object.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask your teacher for some help and hints?

Comment: I find it cleaner to assign multiple variables at once to a struct .e.g. `inventory[*pSize] = (PRODUCT){.number=3456, .onHand=12, .wholesale=12.34, .retail=23.99};`. Just don't forget to specify the type, or the compiler won't be happy

Comment: _how do I make use of the Hammer product?_ You need to ask/clarify whoever gave you the assignment what the requirements are (or add them to the question if you know). You might as well be holding up a real hammer and asking "what do I do with this?" There's many things you can do, it depends on what you _need_ to do.

Comment: if you need to add the hammer to `inventory`, then you can do what Someprogrammerdude said in the 2nd comment. But considering there's an entire function, `fillInProducts`, presumably dedicated to populating the `inventory` with initial objects, it seems out of place to put anything in the `inventory` before the call to that.

Comment: I asked, however, my question was kinda ghosted by the professor...So I'm trying the google university hahaha...I just want to do the same as the function the most straightforward possible like the MANA624 example. (Tks btw! :D)